# Learning Spring with Spring in Practice book, getting exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException:, while executing recipe 4.1

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring using the book Spring in Practice, I am running myself against the wall with the example of recipe 4.1. The code of the example is here https://github.com/springinpractice/sip04

I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [97] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\username\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\com.springinpractice.04_02\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\users\registrationForm_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:580)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

I don't know if this is a problem of accessing the wrong http address, I get the error accessing to this address 
http://localhost:8080/com.springinpractice.04_02/users/new.

This is my XML configuration (it's the same as in the example downloaded from GitHub):

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>appName</param-name>
        <param-value>SiP University</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>recipe</param-name>
        <param-value>4.2</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>aboutThisRecipe</param-name>
        <param-value><![CDATA[
            <p>In recipe 4.2 we replace hardcoded strings in the JSPs with externalized strings. This supports
            internationalization. It also supports a separation of duties between developers and, for example, user
            experience specialists.</p>
        ]]></param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:/spring/beans-web.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

beans-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
========================================================================================================================
beans-web.xml

Copyright (c) 2013 Manning Publications Co.

Willie Wheeler (willie.wheeler@gmail.com)

Book: http://manning.com/wheeler/
Blog: http://springinpractice.com/
Code: https://github.com/springinpractice
========================================================================================================================
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/home.html" view-name="extras/home" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/users/registration_ok.html" view-name="users/registrationOk" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springinpractice.ch04.web" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
        p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="classpath:/spring/messages" />
</beans>
```

Thank you very much for your help. I know this is another newbie question but I could not find the solution by looking to the other questions.

Comment: Are you using tomcat ? If so , what is the version of `servlet-api` jar and tomcat  ?

Comment: Hi I am using Tomcat v8.0, for the  `servlet-api` in the book from what I understand the authors are using their own pack JAR `com.springinpractice.deps-web`. I am using the same version from GitHub so I think that there is no code errors or maybe I am accessing the wrong URL address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own questions because I ended up finding the solution, so if someone else finds this problem again here it goes:

The WebApp does not run directly in Tomcat v8.0 due to the error of the question. In Tomcat v6.0 gives error Unable to read TLD “META-INF/c.tld” from JAR file.

The solution is running it in Jetty and then the correct address to point is http://localhost:8080/sip/users/new.html